# Convergence almost surely

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let $X_n$ and $X$ be random variables. If $X_n \to X$ almost surely, then we have that
$$ \mathbb{P}\left( \lim_{n \to \infty} X_n = X\right) = 1. $$

My question is, can we conclude that
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} X_n = X $$
holds?

Thanks.

Comment: What does $\lim_{n\to\infty} X_{n} = X$ mean?

Comment: Have you though of the related but simpler question: does $P(A=B)=1$ implies $A=B$ ?

Answer (score 3):

Only on a subset of all outcomes.

Consider a infinite sequence of independent tosses of an unbiased coin. The law of large number says that the proportion of heads tends to $1/2$ almost surely. But the experiment also has possible outcomes like "heads on all tosses", "two tails followed by a head repeated forever" or outcomes where the proportion of heads does not have a limit at all. What the law of large numbers tells us that all such outcomes taken together have probability $0$.

But in many applications you can limit your analysis to the probability $1$ set on which $X_n \to X$ with the cost that your own conclusions would also hold only almost surely. But that is often the best that you can do.